# How to encrypt a message using an EOS public key and decrypt with the EOS private key?

Tags: keys, public-key, private-key, message, encryption

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. Can one encrypt a message using their EOS public key and then decrypt this message using their private key? I'm taking the approach of how one would use a PGP key for encrypting email messages and then decrypting it with the PGP private key.

If this isn't possible using EOS keys, what are some possible work around using EOS public key information of a user to encrypt a message and where the user is only able to decrypt with their private key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can encrypt a message using an EOS key. The keys are WIF keys and are compatible with any bitcoin software that takes public and private keys for encrypted messaging or verifying a signed message.